# Blender Python - Force reload of module while importing all its classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, blender

I am developing in Python/Blender, and have two needs here:

1. Import all the individual classes from my module (because they must each be registered with blender)
2. Reload the module itself each time the script is executed (to prevent caching while I'm developing the plugin and press "reload scripts")

Currently I am doing this (in `__init__.py`):

```
from importlib import reload
from .MyPlugin import *

reload(MyPlugin)

classes = [ClassA, ClassB, ClassC]
# register each class, not shown here
```

However the `reload(MyPlugin)` line causes an error: "MyPlugin is not defined".

Originally I tried reloading each of the classes instead, but it raised an error that `reload` expects a module.

Comment: using `import MyPlugin` then you can reload it

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes, but then how can I get each of the individual classes? I tried `inspect.getmembers(MyModule, inspect.isclass)` but the list returns empty. The classes in the module are things like `class MyProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):`

Comment: I can't reproduce that, I can see the classes when I inspect a module using the same function and predicate

Comment: It must be something about Blender execution context then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some colleagues helped me with an answer, what ended up working was this in `__init__.py`:

```
from importlib import reload

if "MyModule" in locals():
    reload(MyModule)
else:
   import MyModule

from .MyModule import *
```

This is detailed here: https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-reload-add-on-code/1202715/2

Answer (score 0):

this works with older Version (tested with 2.79)
Restart first!

```
del sys.modules['foo']    
from foo import *
```